# problemas em depuração com xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Sou iniciante no mundo da programação e recentemente conheci o Xamarin e resolvi aprender um pouco sobre ele.
Na hora de emular os apps eu pesquisei como poderia debugar *(ou depurar, não tenho certeza qual o termo certo)* pelo celular, e eu achei um tutorial básico no site oficial da Microsoft, reforçado pelo curso online que eu estava fazendo, os passos para depuração eram:

1. Deixar o celular no modo desenvolvedor
2. Habilitar a opção "depuração USB"

Conectando o celular ao PC com um cabo USB, em teoria deveria aparecer a opção de depurar usando o celular, em vez do emulador padrão.

Isso não deu certo, o PC simplesmente não mostra essa opção, eu já tentei testar todas as portas USB, usar o celular como MIDI, usar outros 2 aparelhos que as pessoas aqui de casa tem e criar novos projetos para testar, nada deu certo.

Alguém já teve algum problema similar?

Uso o **Windows 10**, tentei debugar em um **LG G7 Thinq**, um **Moto G5S** e em um **LG K7**

Comment: Você instalou um sdk compatível com o aparelho? Instalou o driver usb da Google?

Comment: eu não sei de fato como ver se o sdk é compativel, mas eu tentei instalar o driver da google e não deu nenhuma diferença

Answer (score 0):

Depurar é o termo em português. Você fez o procedimento correto, que seria habilitar o modo desenvolvedor e a depuração USB.

Poderia inicializar o Visual Studio em modo administrador após reinicializar o computador.

Verifique também se aparece uma mensagem no celular perguntando se o aparelho deve confiar no computador e se o projeto de inicialização é o projeto Android.